# Moving a label without having it nest under a screen filling UIView

Tags: swift

I have a UIView implementing a GMSMapView which stretches to fill out the screen. I want a little label displaying text on top of this map on the top-right corner.

I managed to re-order the arrangement to successfully display it on top of the map while in the center:

[image]

But the moment I try to move it to another spot, it nests under `Map Label` and no longer shows up:

[image]

How can I prevent it nesting under the `Map Label` view?

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the constrains, can you us the constrains?

Comment: So I had removed the 'Constrain to margin' and put in 0's for all 4 fields in the 'Pin' options menu to have it fill the entire screen. I got rid of the constraint and still notice the same behavior.

Comment: Can you update the questions with images of the constrains?

Comment: @Francesc I removed the constraints and am still facing the same issues: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ULmnk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all constrains from the label, and then center the label in the middle of the View aligned perfectly. Then go to *Resolve Auto Layout Issues* and click *Update Constrains* after add *Missing Constrains* and run the app. Another way that I use stack the label and place in the middle and add the appropriate constrains. To add a *Stack View* select your label and click on the first icons horizontally placed on the `PIN` row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I I need to position the label in the top right, not the center. Also, after I do add missing constraints, it gives me an X and Y axis, and after that the 'Update Constraints'  is greyed out.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at it on github I see that you have it uploaded give me a few minutes.

Comment: If you want to place it top right, the X = 557 and the Y = 28

Comment: Haha kudos for digging it out! I haven't checked in the removal of the constraints yet.

Comment: Oh you mean programmatically? Or can I do that via storyboard? I did try looking for that option, but couldn't find it.

Comment: You're not gonna believe this, but I managed to move it around by using the arrow keys! Dragging and dropping was nesting it under the UIView, but arrow keys worked. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: hmm interesting... You should add Trailing Space and and Top Space, if you're planning to use this on multiple devices. Thank you. http://i.imgur.com/DtRJ3Ea.png

Comment: Perfect that actually works really well on all devices thanks.